# Use of Comparator interface Java - Sort files

Tags: java, generics, comparator

I have a program to sort files in a certain directory of the computer. I am using the Comparator-interface and using the collections.sort-method but I cannot access the output - from the calling-class. I neither know how to sort the objects in the Sort-class either.

1) Would be glad if someone could tell how I use the compare-method (prototyp is: sort(List list, Comparator c)

2) How do I get the output in the directory class? Because Sort-class is parameterisized I cannot access the method **public String getName()**

*class Directory that creates object of class Sort and put those in an Arraylist (member of Sort)*

```
 private Sort sort = new Sort();
 file = new File(System.getProperty(dir));
 File[] files = getFiles(); // return only files, not directories;

 for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    sort.arrayList.add(new Sort(files[i])); // put those in an ArrayList belonging to sort
 }

list(sort); // call list-method



public void list(Comparator<File> sortOrder) {
    Collections.sort(sort.arrayList, sortOrder);

// now - how do I get the sorted fileNames from here?
}
```

the Sort-class

```
public class Sort<File> implements Comparator<Sort<File>> {

private File file;
public ArrayList <Sort> arrayList = new ArrayList <Sort> ();


public Sort(File file) {
    this.file = file;
}

public Sort() {

}

public String getName() {
    return this.file.toString();
}

// callback-method. Used when calling Collections.sort() in the other class.
public int compare(Sort<File> n1, Sort<File> n2){
 // how do I sort objects on Filesnames.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First things first, if you want the `Comparator` to compare `File` then tell it *that*:

```
public class Sort implements Comparator<File> {

    @Override
    public int compare(File n1, File n2){
        return n1.getName().compareTo(n2.getName);
    }    

}
```

You are asking it to compare instances of *itself*. And the declaration `Sort<File>` tells the compiler that you want a [generic `class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) where the generic type parameter happens to be called `File`. This has nothing to do with the `File` `class`.

In order to use this `Comparator` all you need to do is:

```
final File file = new File(System.getProperty(dir));
final File[] files = file.listFiles();
Arrays.sort(files, new Sort());
for(final File f : files) {
    //do something with f
}
```

Or better yet, simply use an [anonymous `class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html), this will prevent you from doing anything odd with the `Comparator`:

```
Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(File o1, File o2) {
        return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
    }
});
```

But, if you are using Java 8, you can skip this mess entirely:

```
final Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty(dir));
final List<Path> files = new ArrayList<>();
try (final DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(path)) {
    stream.forEach(files::add);
}
files.sort(Comparator.comparing(Path::getFileName));
```

Now you have a sorted `List<Path>`, you can do whatever you want with it. For example to print the sorted list to the console:

```
files.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: +1 for your answer - but  what if I still need to use the list-method, i.e. public void list(Comparatator<File> sortOrder) ?

Comment: What does the `list` method do? It only takes the `Comparator` and nothing to compare...

Comment: I should have mentioned that the list comes from an interface - so it has to  be implemented. Its just supposed to receive an object from Sort and then call collections.sort using this object. That is **list(sort)** . You can see it in my question.

Answer (score -1):

You simply need to loop through the values and perform whatever the required tasks are on those values.

So in your example:

```
public void list(Comparator<File> sortOrder) {
    Collections.sort(sort.arrayList, sortOrder);

// now - how do I get the sorted fileNames from here?
   for (Sort<File> arrayList : file) {
     System.out.println("Sorted list filenames: " + file.getName());
     /* ... other actions ... */
   }

}
```

It should be that simple provided you have implemented the correct generic [comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) methods

Comment: thanks - but Eclipse complains about this - underlining "file" in the for loop: **can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable.**

Comment: You've missed all of the issues in the OPs code. This suggestion doesn't fix anything.