# Getting errors while trying to use Comparator

Tags: java

I do not know what I'm doing wrong but when I try initialize `public final Comparator<K> cmp` to a value, I get an error.

```
public class FastGetListMM<K,V> extends AbstractListMM<K,V> {

    // Comparator used to sort elements; may be null if elements are Comparable
    public final Comparator<K> cmp;    
    private List<K> keys;;
    private List<V> values;

    // Assume elements must be comparable
    public FastGetListMM(ArrayList<K> keys, ArrayList<V> values)
    {
        super(keys, values);
        //this.cmp = new Comparator<K>(); <<----error
    }

    // Use the given comparator to sort the keys
    public FastGetListMM(Comparator<K> cmp)
    {
        super(cmp); <<-----error
        //this.cmp = cmp;  <<----error
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Does your `AbstractListMM` class has an comparator?

Comment: `Comparator` is interface, you cannot instantiate it by `new` directly. Or you need to instantiate anonymous class for it.

Comment: @Razib, no it does not have.

Comment: @SMcCrohan `Cannot instantiate the type Comparator<K>`

Comment: Why didn't you search just how to sort objects using a comparator? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28644484/use-of-comparator-interface-java-sort-files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By this:

```
this.cmp = new Comparator<K>();
```

you try to instantiate [interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) directly, which is not allowed. You must first to create class implementing `Comparator<K>`, or instantiate anonymous class, like:

```
this.cmp = new Comparator<K>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(K k1, K k2) {
        // compare k1 and k2 here
    }
}
```

or assign a lambda, like:

```
Comparator<K> cmp = (k1, k2) -> { /* compare k1 to k2 */ };
```

---

If you prefer classes, use following idiom:

```
public static class MyComparator<K> implements Comparator<K> {
    @Override
    public int compare(K k1, K k2) {
        // compare k1 to k2
    }
}
```

Then, in outer code instantiate this class:

```
Comparator<K> cmp = new MyComparator<>();
```

Comment: @JonK `Comparator` *is* an interface; see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: @TNT That's what I get for rushing! I'm going to shush and go home.

Comment: I tried that, @SashaSalauyou, what whatever I try i get this `Cannot instantiate the type Comparator<K>`. Is there something I need to do? Should I put `implements Comparator` in the name of the class?

Comment: The lambda expression will throw an error since it is unknown whether the type of `K` implements `java.lang.Comparable`. In order for it to work `MyComparator<K>` would have to be `MyComparator<K extends Comparable<? super K>>`.

Comment: @TNT it was just for example. If you compare hashcodes (for example), type of K can be unbounded.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou, so I have to create another class in order to assign the value for the `final` variable, right?

Comment: @John any of mentioned idioms, it doesn't matter. What really matters, that you cannot instantiate interface directly.